# "could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB" error

Tags: java, android

I got this message when I run the emulator, yet the application was running well. Please help me how to solve it.

```
[2013-03-12 12:58:08 - tes] ------------------------------
[2013-03-12 12:58:08 - tes] Android Launch!
[2013-03-12 12:58:08 - tes] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-12 12:58:08 - tes] Performing com.example.tes.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-03-12 12:58:08 - tes] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'andro-google8'
[2013-03-12 12:58:08 - tes] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'andro-google8'
[2013-03-12 12:58:12 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2013-03-12 12:58:12 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2013-03-12 12:58:12 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-03-12 12:58:12 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-03-12 12:58:12 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-03-12 12:58:12 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-03-12 12:58:12 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-03-12 12:58:12 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-03-12 12:58:12 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-03-12 12:58:12 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-03-12 12:58:12 - tes] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-03-12 12:58:12 - tes] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

Comment: I get this error while using Remote Desktop

Answer (score 0):

Try the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407501/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-error).

You may also try to increase the memory of your emulator.