# My sample doesn't start in android virtual device

Tags: android

I'm newbie at android programming. I've just a form and there is only a textbox and button. When i run it i gives me an error that you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

My manifest.xml is below.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.deitel.welcome"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="welcome" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Log**

```
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Welcome] ------------------------------
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Welcome] Android Launch!
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Welcome] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Welcome] Performing com.deitel.welcome.welcome activity launch
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Welcome] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'emulator1'
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Welcome] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'emulator1'
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-17 14:40:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-06-17 14:40:39 - Welcome] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-06-17 14:40:39 - Welcome] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-06-17 14:41:25 - Welcome] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-17 14:41:25 - Welcome] Uploading Welcome.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-17 14:41:25 - Welcome] Installing Welcome.apk...
[2013-06-17 14:42:24 - Welcome] Success!
[2013-06-17 14:42:24 - Welcome] Starting activity com.deitel.welcome.welcome on device emulator-5554
[2013-06-17 14:42:26 - Welcome] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.deitel.welcome/.welcome }
```

Comment: The screenshot is useless. You should look into the logcat output and post it here if you still can't find the root problem.

Comment: Please provide a stack trace for this.

Comment: post log cat output or code.

Comment: try un-installing the application, clean- build your project and then run the project..

Comment: I added the stack trace. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Have you looked at this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407501/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-error

Comment: This is not the log output you need to look at. Here : how to open logcat in eclipse => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280051/how-to-enable-logcat-console-in-eclipse-for-android.  then post the logcat stacktrace here.

Answer (score 1):

This shows that your application is crashing due to some reason.
Debug your Main `Activity` in your case it is Welcome.java. Place debug point in your `onCreate` and other callback methods, i.e `onResume()`, `onPuase()`, Also provide complete stack-trace, what trace you have provided is useless. Please also privide code of your Welcome Activity.