# Android Emulator: could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-4.4-kitkat

I am getting this error in the android emulator logs since I updated the SDKManager and `ADT: [2014-03-12 12:30:05 - Emulator]` could not get `wglGetExtensionsStringARB` What does it mean? And is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: This question is repeated: Could not get wglgetextensionsstringarb[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407501/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-error

Answer (score 2):

I found some people suggest to ignore this error, this is a good option only when your emulator initiating but in my case I ignore this error and my emulator was being start but after that my app didn't appear in that emulator. Then I realized this non-appearance could be because of any incorrect coding in my source file so I create another hello world project which was appearing fine in emulator then I compare my main manifest.xml file with the manifest.xml file of my hello world project. I've some unneccessary or probably miss codes exist in main manifest.file I replace them with my hello world manifest file via copy pasting. Finally all working for me. If you're app still not appearing then try to find your app name in manage file tab of emulator (manage app tab could be appear when pressing menu button at the home screen) if your app name exist there, it means you need to refresh or relode your emulator to make it appear.

Thank hopefully it would be hopeful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

That's means that,

When you create the emulator, you need to choose properties CPU/ABI is Intel Atom (Which will be installed it in SDK manager)

OR

You have unchecked the Checkbox

```
Go to AVD Manager -> Select the device -> Click Edit
```

and Uncheck the Enabled checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

### In the Emulation options -> `Check Use Host GPU` and restart the emulator

[image]