# Does not work my emulator got this error

Tags: android

I have access to a Virtual Machine in my office's network through RDP. I am trying to setup my Android Project on that, but unfortunately the android emulator does not start on that VM. It shuts down with the following error in the Android Studio console:

> Could not initialize emulator framebuffer ERROR: Could not create renderer: Couldn't find matching render driver

I searched the internet and found that it has something to do with OpenGL. RDP does not support OpenGL 2.0 which is required by the emulator. I also tried to use Genymotion but it also failed with the error related to OpenGL.

So is there any work around or any other solution/alternative to start the emulator on a RDP?

Comment: Have you tried changing API version?

Comment: yes i tried all of thing..any have idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

> Not Inside a VM - You cannot run a VM-accelerated emulator inside another virtual machine, such as a VirtualBox or VMWare-hosted virtual machine. You must run the emulator directly on your system hardware.

Sorry, you need a real machine

Comment: Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[ Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[ Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[ Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[- Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[Emulator] Could not initialize emulated framebufferERROR: Could not create renderer: Couldn't find matching render driver

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions found in SO just searching this error message? ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26378237/225503), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407501/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-error) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348905/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb)? Also: you get this error while running inside a VM or in a real PC?

Comment: Just for the record: due to lots of problems with the Android Emulator I tend to use always a connected real device. Always. Not Genymotion, not anything. When I need to use a fast emulator I use the Intel HAXM accelerator. I've faced no problems