# Can't start AVD, but worked already in the same environment (Android)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I hope someone can help.

I can't start my AVD:

[image]

[image]

My development environment is running in a guest of a vmware-workstation.

It was already running for about 2 years in my VM, so I am sure that should be possible. I don't know since when it is not working.

I also reinstalled the entire Android-SDK, but still the same problem.

Do someone has a hint ?

Suggested "duplicated" question doesn't help, because it says that the avd must run on a real hardware and not in a VM, but my AVD runned 2 years in my VM, so I am sure it would work. (In the meanwhile I had some Windows7 Updates and also installed SDK 22, but I don't see any problem with it ? )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does not work my emulator got this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231061/does-not-work-my-emulator-got-this-error)

Comment: I don't think so. I checked a lot of AVD errors in stackoverflow, but nothing helped. referenced link says its only possible on real hardware and not in VM. But I know it worked in the VM, because I worked now more then 2 years in the same VM and with the simulator too. Its strange thats its not working anymore :-(

Comment: I went a bit further on this. I updated to Workstation 11 and checked the "Accelerate 3D graphics" in the "Display" option in the "Virtual Machione Settings". I see device is starting but it stocks with the black screen and the "Android" text in it. Will research further...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what was the real reason to solve the problem but I did the following :

- I had Workstation 9 and I updated to Workstation 11. ( I don't think thats needed )
- I checked the "Accelerate 3D graphics" in the "Display" option in the "Virtual Machine Settings" (I guess this has done the trick, but failed before of wrong sequence trying stuff)
- I created a new AVD

It took about 10 Minutes to start the AVD but it worked.