# Running an AVD in a virtual machine

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm running Studio 2.3 on a brand new Windows 10 client running on a VM hosted by Hyper-V.  I've installed Haxm and disabled Hyper-V with bcdedit.

I cannot get an emulated device to start or launch.

The emulator app (qemu-system-i386) crashed every time it launched right away.  I changed the Graphics setting under emulated performance to Software.  It no longer crashed right away, just sat at the device frame with a black screen and never booted (never even read 'Android').

Anything I can do to troubleshoot?

Thanks,
-Ben

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729150/is-it-possible-to-run-android-device-emulator-via-android-studio-2-on-vmware Check this, It probably doesn't work on virtual machines, you will have to use a arm based emulator though it is slow.

Comment: ARM images have the exact same problem for me.  No difference in the outcome.

Comment: Making a guess, does disabling hyper-V has anything to do with this?

Comment: This appears to be not possible.  I was able to to install Android directly on it's own machine however, hosted in Hyper-V, and connect to it with adb so I've made some progress.