# could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

Android Studio 2.1.2 under Windows 10 professional - 4GB RAM HD 500GB

Getting Message:

> init: could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
>
> emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB
>
> getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
>
> Hax is enabled
>
> Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
>
> Hax ram_size 0x30000000
>
> HAX is working and emulator runs in faast virt mode.
>
> console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
>
> emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '--gpu
>   off' to disable it.
>
> Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

How to solve this problem?

Comment: edit your question clearly please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android emulator: could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407501/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-error)

Comment: Yes, I found several messages that looked like the one that I have. Unfortunately my message was "could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!" with the word FIND and not GET as in all other messages. That is funny: two messages that looks like but has total different understanding.

Answer (score 27):

1. Go to AVD Manager.
2. Edit Virtual Device you create (for example: Nexus_5_API_24 ).
3. Click **Advance Settings** button.
4. In **Emulated Performance** row change **Graphics** to Software **GLES 2.0**
5. In **Memory** row change **RAM** field to **512**.
6. finish.

perhaps it will solve your problem such in my case.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the main solution for all various problems related to Device not launching.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue on Windows 10.1. To fix:

1. Update your system display drivers.
2. Restart computer.
3. Retry emulator.

Comment: Thats it, computer restart was not needed

Answer (score 2):

Experiencing this issue in 2020 and successfully resolved it, hope this helps someone to avoid hours of struggling.

Such error **MIGHT** also occur when the GPU acceleration is somehow disabled on your device.

In my case, in windows, it **was** active, although I had **two monitors** linked to my pc through a **USB-C DELL all in one adapter**.

Because of the adapter, the GPU acceleration was disabled by default (for unknown reasons), so a good debug step to understand if that's the issue is to simply detach the USB-C docking station / adapter (if any monitor is linked to it) and to run the emulator. If the emulator runs, the issue is that the GPU acceleration is not working as intended.

I wasn't able to solve the issue WITH the adapter yet (my drivers are up to date already for my NVidia), but I managed to open an issue.

Comment: This occurs with the Dell D6000 dock, cannot start the emulator with Android studio on a screen supported by the dock.  Have to output direct HDMI or mini-DVI from the laptop to be able to run the emulator!

Comment: This happened when I switched to a more modern monitor. Able to get back working by disconnecting from monitor and power cycling. Noter running the emulator directly from the command line is useful here since the log messages are more extensive.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, [briosheje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275797/briosheje) !

That was the same issue with my laptop as well. I have both Intel Iris Xe Graphics with GPU and NVidia GeForce graphics with GPU. I have set the NVidia GPU as the default.  I had updated the device drivers, and made sure the GPU is active. But, the Android AVD manager kept giving the same error described in the original post.

Your post gave me the clue. I also have 2 external monitors connected via USB cables. That sure appears to be the problem.

I do have a fix. When I run the AVD manager from the laptop's built in display, I am able to use the host GPU. I can then move the emulated phone to the external monitor display, and there are no issues! A small inconvenience to launch the emulator from the laptop's built in display, but after that, you can work with the emulator on the external big monitors.

There are few other articles that suggest using software based acceleration. When it comes to working with animations, software based accelerations do a poor job. The display is choppy, plus the system CPU reaches and stays at 100% for the duration of the animation. With the host GPU based emulation, the CPU usage stays less than 25% !! In the window task manager, under the GPU and the GPU engine columns, I can clearly see the GPU getting utilized.