# Jenkins Android Emulator Plugin not running

Tags: jenkins, android-emulator, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to explore and use the Jenkins Android Emulator plugin in order to run my emulator within a CI environment. I have so far tried 3 different methods but none of them is able to run the emulator

**Method 1:Using an existing emulator**

[Screenshot of the first method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ovMt.jpg)

In the job's configuration , Select ***Run an Android emulator during build***, then ***Run existing emulator***. In the ***AVD name*** I insert Nexus5X_6_8664 then Jenkins is able to find it.

When i run the job it gives me the following error :

```
Started by user Amine
Building in workspace D:\jenkins\workspace\Emulator
[android] Using Android SDK: D:\Tools\Dev\sdk\
$ D:\Tools\Dev\sdk\/platform-tools/adb.exe start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5857 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ D:\Tools\Dev\sdk\/platform-tools/adb.exe start-server
[android] Starting Android emulator
$ D:\Tools\Dev\sdk\/tools/emulator.exe -engine classic -ports 5768,5769 -report-console tcp:5833,max=60 -avd Nexus5X_6_8664 -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
emulator: device fd:964

HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: WARNING: Requested adb port (5769) is outside the recommended range [5555,5586]. ADB may not function properly for the emulator. See -help-port for details.
[android] Emulator reported that the console is available on port 5 768
[android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
$ D:\Tools\Dev\sdk\/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5768 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
ERROR: Timeout after 45000 milliseconds

$ D:\Tools\Dev\sdk\/platform-tools/adb.exe kill-server
Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

*More details :*

- I have increased VMHeap, changed graphics to automatic, Hardware GLES 2.0 or Software GLES 2.0 (as in [Android emulator: could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407501/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-error)  or [could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888729/could-not-find-wglgetextensionsstringarb))
- I have Tried many screen resolutions
- I have added window.x = 0  window.y = 0  to @Nexus5X_6_8664.ini

**Method 2:Creating a new emulator**

[Screenshot of the second method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLm8T.jpg)

In the job's configuration , Select "Run an Android emulator during build", then "Run emulator with properties" :

- Android OS version    : android-23
- Screen density : hdpi
- Screen resolutions : 480x800
- Device locale : en_US
- SD card size : 64M
- Target ABI    : x86_64
- Emulator name suffix

When i run the job it gives me the following error :

```
Started by user Amine
Building in workspace D:\jenkins\workspace\Emulator
[android] Using Android SDK: D:\Tools\Dev\sdk\
[android] Creating Android AVD: C:\Users\Amine\.android\avd\hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_mySuffix.avd
[android] D:\Tools\Dev\sdk\/tools/android.bat create avd -f -a -c 64M -s WVGA800 -n hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-23_x86_64_mySuffix -t android-23 --abi x86_64
[android] Could not create Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD config file
Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

When i run the same command above on my command line manually to investigate te errors it gives the following error :

```
Error: Flag '-s' is not valid for 'create avd'.
```

I try to remove `-s` and then `-t` then it requests :

```
Error: Package path (-k) not specified. Valid system image paths are:
system-images;android-23;default;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86
system-images;android-23;default;x86_64
system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86_64
system-images;android-23;default;x86
system-images;android-23;google_apis;armeabi-v7a
```

**Method 3: Using command lines instead of Android Emulator Plugin**

[Screenshot of the third method][3]

I have then decided to drop the Android emulator plugin and start using a regular Windows batch command from jenkins with the following lines :

```
D:
cd D:\Tools\Dev\sdk\tools\ 
D:\Tools\Dev\sdk\tools\emulator.exe @Nexus5X_6_8664
```

When i Run "adb devices" on separated command line I am able to view my emulator finally running; However the emulator's window is not displayed and it keeps displaying the following error :

```
D:\Tools\Dev\sdk\tools>D:\Tools\Dev\sdk\tools\emulator.exe @Nexus5X_6_8664 
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
OpenGL backend 'angle' without OpenGL ES 1.x library detected. Using GLESv2 only.
eglMakeCurrent failed
eglMakeCurrent failed
eglMakeCurrent failed
eglMakeCurrent failed
```

Please note if i run `D:\Tools\Dev\sdk\tools\emulator.exe @Nexus5X_6_8664` from my command line manually I'm not having any problem as the errors above.

*More details :*

- Jenkins services are running with my Login/Password access rights as an administrator. (I have followed cloudbees tutorial and it works fine)
- I have added window.x = 0  window.y = 0  to @Nexus5X_6_8664.ini

Comment: I have done more research on the issues above, it appears that the Jenkins plugin is very unstable and does not follow Android SDK updates See Section known issues here : https://plugins.jenkins.io/android-emulator

Comment: "Could not create Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD config file" sounds like the avd was created with an incompatible version of android sdk. Suggest trying to delete and recreate an avd and see if problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

On the issue with Method 1: 
Can you try updating to the latest version of SDK tools. We had similar issue and it got fixed after latest updates.

Update the below and try again :

1. Android Emulator [27.2.9 (May 2018)]
2. Android SDK Platform Tools
3. Android SDK Tools
4. Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)

follow the below thread on how to update: 
[Emulator: ERROR :detected a hanging thread 'Qt event loop'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153222/emulator-error-detected-a-hanging-thread-qt-event-loop)