# Emulator: ERROR :detected a hanging thread 'Qt event loop'

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I run API 27 emulator, I get:

> ERROR :detected a hanging thread 'Qt event loop'

I have an Image that shows the error:

[image]

Comment: What if you delete and re-create the emulator? And does this affect any other API levels?

Comment: Also make sure your tools are up to date. There was [a fix for an issue that sounds similar to yours](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html#27-1-10) in release 27.1.10

Comment: Can you tell me how to update the tool located in android studio?

Comment: `Tools > Android > SDK Manager`. Click on the `SDK Tools` tab, and if the right-hand column says "Update Available" then click the checkbox then OK. My current version for the Emulator is 27.1.12.

Comment: I upadated and resolved the first problem .But when I run the emulator now, it occured 2 problems        Emulator:error: failed to allocate initial memory for ColorBuffer of size 1440 &

adb.exe - Application Error(In window form)

Comment: Try reducing the amount of RAM your emulator uses. Edit your AVD, click `Show Advance Settings` and lower the RAM value to 1024 or below. Else, try to create a new AVD that's a bit less RAM-hungry.

Comment: I reduced the ram and it camed the simulator interface.Thank you, But I see the problem occured inside the emulator "pixel launcher isn't responding with Close app and wait options"

Comment: By the sounds of things your computer might not be capable of running the emulator with recent API levels. Don't worry, my c.2010 Intel i3 desktop can't run an emulator with any decent speed either, it pretty much grinds to a halt. Hit "wait" and see if anything happens.

Comment: In the meantime I'll summarize these comments as an answer so we can mark this question as closed, as the original issue has now been resolved.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.But the process is stucked even the android studio is stucked."Not responding" message appear at the android studio window when click the android studio.It says "Gradle building running" but does not scroll the indicator.

Comment: Sounds like your PC can't handle the emulator and Android Studio at the same time then. Exactly the same happens for me on my home desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this was a bug in the Android Emulator [that was fixed in release 27.1.10](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html#27-1-10). Check if your emulator is up to date by going to `Tools > Android > SDK Manager` and clicking the `SDK Tools` tab:

[image: SDK Tools Screenshot]

The current latest version at the time of writing this answer is **27.1.12**. If there is an update available, the Status in the right-hand column will say "Update Available". Click the checkbox and OK, and your emulator will update.

Comment: Thank you very much @Michael Dodd. You fixed my request problem.