# Android Studio emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU1 thread'. on Windows

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, qemu

I am getting this error with Android Studio 3.0.1 on Windows 7.

I am well aware there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153222/emulator-error-detected-a-hanging-thread-qt-event-loop). However my Android Emulator is up to date at version 27.1.12 so the solution is irrelevant.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: @ataravati sadly no. It would like to say it disappeared, but another emulator nightmare replaced it :(

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue after installing 27.1.12.

The Android Emulator version is now 27.2.9 and your issue should be now fixed with this. Do update intel HAXM accelerator as well.