# Android Studio AVD Emulator is not working

Tags: android, android-studio

Following are the errors I am facing while running the android emulator in an android studio.

```
1:44 PM Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString!

1:44 PM Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!

1:44 PM Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!

1:44 PM Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

1:44 PM Emulator: Warning: requested RAM 1536M too high for your system. 
Reducing to maximum supported size 512M

1:44 PM Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: Could not load library 
WinHvPlatform.dll.

1:44 PM Emulator: failed to initialize WHPX: Function not implemented
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/41120289/5815673

Comment: @umang hey let me know u r studio version and one more thing google before posting here. Thank you

Comment: I am using the latest version of android studio 3.2

Comment: @umang, First delete that virtual device, go to SDK Manager and install all the available images under one API for example say api 5.1 then create a new virtual device with 512m and api 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is something related to graphics.

To use Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) on Windows you need an AMD CPU.

Comment: i am using core i5 processor with 4 gb ram.

Answer (score 0):

> qemu-system-x86_64.exe: **Could not load library  WinHvPlatform.dll.**

It seems like it couldn't load `WinHvPlatform.dll` library. Reinstalling or recreating the ADV might help in this case.

> **requested RAM 1536M too high for your system**.  **Reducing to maximum
>   supported size 512M**

Try setting maximum ram to `512mb` in the AVD.

Comment: Changing ram values is disabled for me, see stackoverflow.com/q/55713335/7678788

Answer (score 0):

-->  Go to tools menu.

-->  Go to avd managare.

-->  Edit Virtual Device you create (for example: Nexus_5X_API_27 ).

-->  Click on Advance Settings Button.

-->  In Emulated Performance  change Graphics to Software GLES 2.0

-->  In Memory change RAM field to 512.

-->  finish.

in think it will work. 
all the best.

Comment: Well, I already tried these settings and in the latest version of an android studio, graphics setting was disabled by default. I already reinstall it many times still facing this issue, again and again, I am using 32-bit OS.