# AVD Emulator is not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, ram, whpx

While running the emulator on the android studio, my `Event Log`:

> 17:11 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> **17:11   Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this
>   machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will
>   address this in a future release.**
>
> **17:11   Emulator: Warning: requested RAM 1536M too high for your system.
>   Reducing to maximum supported size 512M**
>
> **17:11   Emulator:
>   C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86\qemu-system-x86_64.exe:
>   Could not load library WinHvPlatform.dll.**
>
> **17:11   Emulator:
>   C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86\qemu-system-x86_64.exe:
>   failed to initialize WHPX: Function not implemented**
>
> 17:11 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
>
> 17:11 Gradle build finished in 2 s 704 ms

All the **bold sentence** were shown in `RED` color.

I am getting `Notification` as:

> Emulator:
>   C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86\qemu-system-x86_64.exe:
>   failed to initialize WHPX: Function not implemented

My SDK Platform:
[image]

My SDK Tools:
[image]

I tried to solve the issue with reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52587220/7678788 (I was unable to change it) so, I took help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52342344/7678788, but this also didn't solve the issue.

```
My SDK Platform and SDK Tools are of the latest version.
```

How to fix this issue?

---

### UPDATE

I have also installed the latest **`Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM)`** and tried to run the emulator, my `Event Log`:

> 19:11 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> **19:11   Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this
>   machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will
>   address this in a future release.**
>
> **19:11   Emulator: Warning: requested RAM 1536M too high for your system.
>   Reducing to maximum supported size 512M**
>
> 19:11 Gradle build finished in 8 s 357 ms
>
> 19:11 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

All the **bold sentence** were shown in `RED` color.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that the emulator (The **emulator ONLY**) ask 512mb of ram as minimum, that isn't recomendable since your system, the android studio, and background process also take ram, to run android studio i'll suggest having at least 4gb of ram, but if that isn't posible you should try to have at least arround 768mb of free ram before running the emulator.

For reference there are some OS ram usage(all on x64 OS)
Windows 7  : 460mb - 540mb
Windows 8  : 1.8gb - 2.4gb 
Windows 10 : 1.5gb - 2.5gb

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Intel x86 Emulator Accelarator (HAXM) and reboot the device. Make sure the emulator is installed properly and reboot Android Studio.

Comment: 19:11 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

**19:11 Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.**

**19:11 Emulator: Warning: requested RAM 1536M too high for your system. Reducing to maximum supported size 512M**

19:11 Gradle build finished in 8 s 357 ms

19:11 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Installed and now it just says the above comment, also when I start debugging there comes two dialog box on the screen goes away immediately

Comment: I still get `Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0`