# Why has my Android Emulator stopped working?

Tags: android, windows, emulation

I am having the problem related to emulator start from Android Studio, from command line.

I do not understand what caused the problem, because before that I was running emulators, did not have any problem. I suppose it is started after Windows 11 updates.

Here is the errors which I see after command line (.\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_Fold_API_33) run:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.1.4.0 (build_id 10865566) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath C:\Users\vro79\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33-ext4\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 6560
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | folded height 2092 is larger than lcd height 1840, reduced to lcd height.
INFO    | Increasing RAM size to 3072MB
INFO    | IPv4 server found:
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 60aa:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 60aa:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 50b0:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 50b0:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 30b6:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 30b6:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 10bc:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 10bc:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: c2:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: c2:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 8c8:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 8c8:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 20ce:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 20ce:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 40dc:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 40dc:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 60e2:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 60e2:1c57:cb01:0:60aa:1c57:cb01:0 (2x)
INFO    | Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
library_mode host gpu mode host
I1004 23:22:11.306659   19732 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
added library vulkan-1.dll
createGlobalVkEmulation:957 Selecting Vulkan device: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti
initialize: Supports id properties, got a vulkan device UUID
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString! arbFound 0 listarbNull/empty 1 0 extFound 0 extNull/empty 1 0 remote 0
OpenGL Core Profile not supported.
E1004 23:22:11.503461   19732 EmulationGl.cpp:94] Failed to find exactly 1 GLES 2.x config: found 0.
E1004 23:22:11.503584   19732 EmulationGl.cpp:300] Failed to validate creating GLES 2.x context.
E1004 23:22:11.503735   19732 FrameBuffer.cpp:333] Failed to initialize GL emulation.
E1004 23:22:11.533432   19732 RendererImpl.cpp:141] Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

I completely removed Android Studio and installed it, then realized it is not related to Android SDK or Android Studio.

Comment: Hi, take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41120289/12177115

Comment: That feature is available when Google Play API is not available in emulator. Otherwise, it is disabled and not available if emaultaor Google Play API is available.

Comment: You can change it through `config.ini` file in emulator path.  It should be `hw.gpu.enabled=yes` and `hw.gpu.mode=software`. The mode takes `auto, host, software` values.

Comment: But that is not a good way to update emulator. Why they closed that feature? Who knows?