# Can't run my app on android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, launch

I have downloaded android studio and now i am trying to run an app.I haven't changed anything in code or design.I am using version 2.2.2
   When i click on run it gives me an error
`init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!`
But emulator opens.Then there is blank black screen for 2-3 minutes,then `android`title for another 5 minutes.This is what i get.[image: this is that i get]

But i don't know where is my app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407501/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-error

Comment: @user1506104 i don't have a checkbox named Enabled

Answer (score 1):

What you're running is Android version 7.1 (Nougat MR1). You can see the list of apps (app drawer) by clicking on the small `^` (caret) icon above the opaque area highlited as a red circle in the picture below

[image]

Comment: I still don't see my app there.

Comment: Then run the app from `Run->Run App` in Android Studio or using the `ctrl + F10` shortcut. Android Studio will inform of any errors while compiling if any

Comment: I do.It tells me to choose an emulator.I choose and it opens this emlator

Comment: It could be bad GPU drivers or improper AVD config. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37144761/3511518) answer

Comment: I don't see Host GPU checkbox on emulator's edit page

Comment: At the moment, I'm not sure if your issue is emulator not running or the app produce error while runtime/compile time?

Comment: I doubt that it is apps problem because i have not changed anything from default code

Comment: It must be with your GPU rendering. Try editing the config and set the "Emulated Performance" to `Automatic`

Comment: Now i get even more errors like `Could not initialize emulated framebuffer` and `Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!`

Answer (score 0):

> emulator opens.Then there is blank black screen for 2-3 minutes,then androidtitle for another 5 minutes.

This is normal. You should wait until the emulator fully boots and run your app again. If your development computer has an Intel processor, be sure to install HAXM. It will greatly increase the speed of the emulator.

Comment: Thanks for the advice,but this is not the answer is it?

Comment: @Papaa Did you try my advice? What happens if you try again after the emulator boots?

Comment: @Papaa Also keep the emulator open. Do not close it in between runs. It should appear in the dialog each time. You can even select the option to always use the same device so that you don't have to see the dialog each time you run your app.

Comment: I downloaded and ran it,,but nothing changed

Comment: @Papaa I suggest you try something simpler than someone else's app. Start a new project with an Activity and see if you can get it to run. If you do everything right, it should show a screen with the words "Hello, World!".

Comment: It's not someone else's app,it's actually newly created project with no code(except default) at all

Comment: @Papaa Sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: @Papaa Do you have a file named MainActivity.java?

Comment: Yes i have got that file

Comment: @papaa Try restarting Android Studio. I find that it hangs sometimes while installing an app on the emulator.

Comment: I have restarted that lots of times.Do you use 2.2.2 also?

Comment: @Papaa yes, I use 2.2.2. I have not had this problem and I am running out of ideas for you.

Comment: Did you start the emulator and wait for it to boot before trying to run your app?

Comment: Of course.You don't have to do this.I will switch to IOS development it is probably easier:D