# Android Studio AVD error GetExtensions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, windows-10, updatecheck

When I launch AVD I get following error messages :->

```
Emulator: emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck : Failure:Error

Emulator:init:Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!

Emulator: emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck : Failure:Error
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: can you update your emulator ?

Comment: I updated my emulator but still the error is there

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407501/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-error

Comment: I am using andriod studio 3.0.1. none of the solutions described there worked for me.