# Unable to Start Android Emulator, Facing several issues

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Android Emulator is annoying me from days. Runs properly for some days and gives somekind of error next day. This time when I click to start emulator, it appears in taskbar and then crashes giving me following errors:

```
Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

I am using Android studio 3.0.1 and Emulator: 27.1.12

Note: I have tried using Software Graphics it reduces performance/responsiveness of Virtual device. My question is it was running perfectly yesterday, what has happened to it today?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android emulator: could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407501/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-error)

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck `Use Host GPU` option in AVD manager.

Comment: One thing I have observed that it works fine after restarting system starts giving this error when I wake up system from sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're having issues with videocard drivers. Try something from this list: set `Graphics` setting of virtual device to `Automatic`, delete and recreate virtual device, update/reinstall videocard drivers.

Comment: One thing I have observed that it works fine after restarting system starts giving this error when I wake up system from sleep.