# emulator not running

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have created one application related to maps using api 16 as soon as run this application this errors pops out.

```
      [2012-10-18 20:05:26 - Maps] Android Launch!
      [2012-10-18 20:05:26 - Maps] adb is running normally.
      [2012-10-18 20:05:26 - Maps] Performing com.example.maps.MainActivity activity launch
      [2012-10-18 20:05:29 - Maps] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'andi'
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1024MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 768MB.
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 1455
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] 
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
      [2012-10-18 20:05:38 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

when i run this application using api 14 it works but it is not working on api 15 and 16

Answer (score 7):

I changed the VM Heap of the Virtual Device to a higher value - this resolved the crash for me.
The values are now: 10.1" WXGA 1280 x 800, Android 4.1.2, Intel Atom, Ram 1024, VM Heap 128, internal Storage 300 MB, SD 300 MB
Further, I changed the start-up settings for the memory in eclipse.ini, but I am not sure whether this is related to the problem or not.

Answer (score 7):

OK I know this is too late for you but it may help someone else. I tried all the solutions given around but none worked for me

Google led me here
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33336
The solution given worked for many but not for me. I include it here since maybe for you it will help

openGL in the wrong folder:
\tools instead of \tools\lib
copy the following files to the tools folder:

```
libEGL_translator.dll
libGLES_CM_translator.dll
libGLES_V2_translator.dll
libOpenglRender.dll
```

However using "Zachary's technique" at the end of the post
For those who cannot get this working.
Go get Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).  Add a filter for 'Process Name' + 'Contains' + 'emulator':
* Start your capture
* fire up the emulator
* wait until you get the failed message
* stop the capture

Search (ctrl + f) the capture for one of the dlls that is failing to load, like "libOpenglRender".  You will probably see several attempts at locating this file across multiple directories with the result "NAME NOT FOUND" or "PATH NOT FOUND".

Using this I found I had an issue with atiglpxx.dll

I looked at me display adapter on my windows device manager and downloaded a driver for in my case ATI Modility Radeon HD 2400 XT from AMD
http://support.amd.com/us/psearch/Pages/psearch.aspx?type=2.4.2&product=2.4.2.3.15&contentType=GPU+Download+Detail&ostype=Windows+8+-+32-Bit+Edition&keywords=&items=20

Once I installed that I no longer got the "could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB" message

Comment: For me copying files to \tools folder did the magic. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

Disable **GPU emulation** by setting it to off in the AVD preferences or by adding `-gpu off` to command line

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, your app requires OpenGL 2.0, emulator didn't support it until recently.

[Android OpenGL ES 2.0 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941016/android-opengl-es-2-0-emulator)
check this link

Answer (score 0):

Go to your AVD manager,  select the AVD you are trying to use and change the Target dropdown to "Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 16".  then save it and restart.

Comment: If you dont see "Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 16"  you will need to use the SDK manager to download it.

Comment: Yes i have done this but not working for me. I have igb ram installed on my system and 512 mb 9600gt graphics card. So is it possible that this is because of low ram.

Comment: Oh,  yea,  you need to buy moar ram for your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to play around with your android device specifications like RAN, Heap and other specification.

It's hard to tell you which must be set to what. In my case I set RAM as 512 and Heap 128 to make it work.