# AVD doesn't launch

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I saw all the answers for this issue, but I didn't get what I want. My problem is: I installed Android Studio and the AVD didn't work even with eclipse. It displays this message:

```
Failed to create Context 0x3005  
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB  
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB  
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.  
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB  
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB  
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB  
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB  
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB  
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB  
Could not initialize emulated framebufferERROR: Could not create renderer: Couldn't find matching render driver
```

Comment: have You seen this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590239/emulator-warning-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulation-using-software-rende

Comment: Check this out also: ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407501/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-error)