# Error running the emulator: "Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it."

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

While running the **emulator** I got error like this

```
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

What should I do?

Comment: Check [this][1]. Hope this will solve your problem. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590239/emulator-warning-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulation-using-software-rende

Comment: Check [this][1]. Hope this will solve your problem. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590239/emulator-warning-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulation-using-software-rende

Comment: include error in title, add relevant tags