# AVD Error on Virtual Machine Hyper-V Windows Server 2008

Tags: android, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device, hyper-v

I have installed **Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate Edition** on Virtual Machine **Hyper-V Windows Server 2008**

**Windows 7 Ultimate Edition Specifications**

- RAM: 1.50 GB
- Processor: Intel Xeon 3.10 GHz
- System Type: 32bit

After that I have installed **Android Development Tool** (ADT) on this Virtual Machine (Windows 7 Ultimate Edition).

**Android**

- Installed Android 32bit adt-bundle
- Updated API level 7, 10, 14, 17, 19

After **Setup Android Virtual Device** When I click on the start Button for run **Android Emulator**. Its shows following Errors

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'NexusS-API17-4.2.2'
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

I tried to find its solution on internet and found this link
[emulator not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957309/emulator-not-running/14605917)
after follow these all suggestions my problem is still there

**How I can run the Android Emulator on this Virtual Operating System for the Development?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May this help you:

Just go to `AVD manager`, Select created AVD & then Edit. Check the box `Use Host GPU`..

---

**OR Try:**

Change the resolution of your screen (Increase)...

---

**OR Try:**

Start `"emulator-arm"` instead of `"emulator".`

---

**OR Try:**

Try setting the RAM to `512 MB`.

---

**OR Try:**

Goto `DDMS` perspective, click on the `down arrow` next to the screen capture camera icon and select `Reset ADB` from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Thanks it works for me.
`RAM 512MB` and `Restart ADB`