# in eclipse emulator is not booting up

Tags: android, emulation

I am new to Android. I have downloaded the [ADT Bundle for windows](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) from android's official site, and then as per their directions I followed all the steps, 
But when I launch the AVD using Eclipse then in the starting popup I am getting this log

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'TestAVD'
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: warning: opening audio output failed
```

and then even I waited for hours to boot the emulator, but it is not booting up.
I am not getting, where I am making mistake. Please help me.

Comment: refer to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941016/android-opengl-es-2-0-emulator/8948724#8948724

Comment: Try to scale down your emulator according to your screen size and monitor dpi. Also give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407501/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-error

Comment: I tried it but still giving same error

Answer (score 0):

According to

**Issue 41032** [Emulator Failed to create Context 0x3005](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41032) you are assigning ram than 512 try to reduce the Ram and then run the AVD it will work

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I set the RAM to 512, still it is giving same error