# OpenGl renderer on Android

Tags: android, render, opengl-2.0

I am trying to make a simple renderer with OpenGL2.0, made up only of a main activity, surface view, and renderer file. Whenever I run it on an avd, the screen turns black and says the program has encountered a problem. Here is the logcat

```
08-04 03:55:59.722: D/libEGL(6287): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to       software renderer.
08-04 03:55:59.821: I/Choreographer(6287): Skipped 292 frames!  The application may be     doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 03:56:00.042: D/libEGL(6287): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
08-04 03:56:00.801: D/gralloc_goldfish(6287): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-04 03:56:00.835: W/dalvikvm(6287): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-04 03:56:00.881: E/AndroidRuntime(6287): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 102
08-04 03:56:00.881: E/AndroidRuntime(6287): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
08-04 03:56:00.881: E/AndroidRuntime(6287):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:863)
08-04 03:56:00.881: E/AndroidRuntime(6287):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
08-04 03:56:00.881: E/AndroidRuntime(6287):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
08-04 03:56:00.881: E/AndroidRuntime(6287):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
08-04 03:56:02.155: I/Choreographer(6287): Skipped 121 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 03:56:07.941: I/Process(6287): Sending signal. PID: 6287 SIG: 9
```

Can the problem be recognized from this or should I provide code as well?

Comment: have you tried this to the device?

Comment: Only on an emulator if that is what you're asking.

Comment: can you show us your emulator configuration?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941016/android-opengl-es-2-0-emulator

Comment: avd platform 4.2.2 - armeabi-v7a - target sdk 17, how can I get more information?

Comment: have you checked the GPU emulation to yes?