# Android SDK emulator not supporting OpenGL es 2.0 error

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I was trying to get Google Map APIv2 working on my Eclipse Android SDK emulator. However, I got the OpenGL not supported warning:

```
09-11 22:32:43.185: E/Google Maps Android API(1236): Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above
09-11 22:32:43.295: D/dalvikvm(1236): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 327K, 13% free 2965K/3408K, paused 94ms, total 95ms
09-11 22:32:43.435: D/dalvikvm(1236): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 137K, 11% free 3167K/3520K, paused 24ms, total 25ms
09-11 22:32:43.435: I/dalvikvm-heap(1236): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.811MB for 635812-byte allocation
09-11 22:32:43.605: D/dalvikvm(1236): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 3788K/4144K, paused 164ms, total 168ms
09-11 22:32:43.904: D/libEGL(1236): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
09-11 22:32:43.914: D/(1236): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a0efdf0, tid 1236
09-11 22:32:43.954: D/libEGL(1236): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
09-11 22:32:43.964: D/libEGL(1236): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
09-11 22:32:44.144: W/EGL_emulation(1236): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-11 22:32:44.154: D/dalvikvm(1236): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 268K, 9% free 4026K/4416K, paused 122ms, total 122ms
09-11 22:32:44.184: D/OpenGLRenderer(1236): Enabling debug mode 0
09-11 22:32:44.234: D/(1236): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1f3190, tid 1257
09-11 22:32:44.969: D/dalvikvm(1236): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 193K, 11% free 4061K/4548K, paused 429ms, total 431ms
```

And my app only shows the zoom in/out button. Even the "Google" trademark is not there.

seems like the OpenGL ES 2.0 should be supported since last year:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html

And I've looked at:[Android OpenGL ES 2.0 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941016/android-opengl-es-2-0-emulator)
And
http://www.learnopengles.com/android-emulator-now-supports-native-opengl-es2-0/

So my AVD is Google API18, platform 4.3. And I've checked "Use Host GPU". And I've also added the following to my main xml:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

Just can't think of the places to go wrong. Any idea would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just ignore those warnings, particularly "eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented".  I have noticed that many of the sample programs in the SDK incorrectly detect if 2.0 is available.  Just ignore it and move on.  If the HelloEffects sample works, you are good to go.  This should help:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1

Comment: Thanks @ClayMontgomery, so could you elaborate more where is the "HelloEffects" sample?

Comment: It's in the Android SDK Samples.  On my system, the path is: C:\Android\sdk\samples\android-17\HelloEffects\src\com\example\android\mediafx\HelloEffects.java

Comment: Thanks. I switched to third party virtual device Genymotion. It is much easier to work on