# Android OGLES2.0 : All applications getting error

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm new to android SDK and programming using OGLES2.0. my problem is, most of the programs are not running on my PC.
I'm using Android virtual Device Nexus 4 with 512 Mb Ram, VM Heap 64, Internal Storage 512 and Android 4.3 with API 18 (No SD Card).

A sample code which I'm trying to run is

```
package com.example.mynewsample;
//
// Book:      OpenGL(R) ES 2.0 Programming Guide
// Authors:   Aaftab Munshi, Dan Ginsburg, Dave Shreiner
// ISBN-10:   0321502795
// ISBN-13:   9780321502797
// Publisher: Addison-Wesley Professional
// URLs:      http://safari.informit.com/9780321563835
//            http://www.opengles-book.com
//

// Hello_Triangle
//
//    This is a simple example that draws a single triangle with
//    a minimal vertex/fragment shader.  The purpose of this 
//    example is to demonstrate the basic concepts of 
//    OpenGL ES 2.0 rendering.

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.util.Log;

public class myTriangleRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
    ///
    // Constructor
    //
    public myTriangleRenderer(Context context)
    {
        mVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mVerticesData.length * 4)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        mVertices.put(mVerticesData).position(0);
    }

    ///
    // Create a shader object, load the shader source, and
    // compile the shader.
    //
    private int LoadShader(int type, String shaderSrc)
    {
        int shader;
        int[] compiled = new int[1];

        // Create the shader object
        shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        if (shader == 0)
            return 0;

        // Load the shader source
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderSrc);

        // Compile the shader
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        // Check the compile status
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);

        if (compiled[0] == 0)
        { 
            Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
            return 0;
        }
        return shader;
    }

    ///
    // Initialize the shader and program object
    //
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config)
    {
        String vShaderStr = 
              "attribute vec4 vPosition;    \n"
            + "void main()                  \n"
            + "{                            \n"
            + "   gl_Position = vPosition;  \n"
            + "}                            \n";

        String fShaderStr = 
              "precision mediump float;                   \n"
            + "void main()                                  \n"
            + "{                                            \n"
            + "  gl_FragColor = vec4 ( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );\n"
            + "}                                            \n";

        int vertexShader;
        int fragmentShader;
        int programObject;
        int[] linked = new int[1];

        // Load the vertex/fragment shaders
        vertexShader = LoadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vShaderStr);
        fragmentShader = LoadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fShaderStr);

        // Create the program object
        programObject = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        if (programObject == 0)
            return;

        GLES20.glAttachShader(programObject, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(programObject, fragmentShader);

        // Bind vPosition to attribute 0
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programObject, 0, "vPosition");

        // Link the program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(programObject);

        // Check the link status
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programObject, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linked, 0);

        if (linked[0] == 0)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error linking program:");
            Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programObject));
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programObject);
            return;
        }

        // Store the program object
        mProgramObject = programObject;

        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    // /
    // Draw a triangle using the shader pair created in onSurfaceCreated()
    //
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused)
    {
        // Set the viewport
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);

        // Clear the color buffer
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use the program object
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramObject);

        // Load the vertex data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mVertices);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }

    // /
    // Handle surface changes
    //
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height)
    {
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
    }

    // Member variables
    private int mProgramObject;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
    private FloatBuffer mVertices;
    private static String TAG = "HelloTriangleRenderer";

    private final float[] mVerticesData =
    { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f };
}
```

I had tried different virtual devices, but each time it says Unfortunately  stops running.
I am getting this with all OGLES2.0 programs, that won't use CANVAS. A Canvas Program is running accurately.

Answer (score 1):

My experience thus far has always been that the Android emulator does not fully support OpenGL ES 2.0, only ES 1.x. By far the easiest approach is to test on a physical device.

However please checkout this question which suggests it can now be done:

[Android OpenGL ES 2.0 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941016/android-opengl-es-2-0-emulator)

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL ES 2.0 emulation on AVDs actually works pretty well now since the Jelly Bean version.  However, the critical factor is the underlying OpenGL driver you have installed on your host development system.  It really must be a recent Nvidia or AMD driver.  Also, installing Intel's HAXM makes it run much faster.  See the third article here:

```
http://montgomery1.com/opengl/
```